# How to pass multiple variables from QT Dialog to Main Window

Tags: c++, qt

I have a press button (pushButton_RenameTargets) and 3 labels (label_Tar1ex, label_Tar2ex, label_Tar3ex) on my main form with default text values. When I push the button (pushButton_RenameTargets) a dialog is created (renametargets). It has three text edit lines (lineEdit_Target1, lineEdit_Target2,lineEdit_Target3). When I enter names on the three text edit lines and push OK I want the 3 labels on my main form to update.

Better Described:

When the button is pressed:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_RenameTargets_clicked()
{
    RenameTargets renametargets;
    renametargets.setModal(true);
    renametargets.exec();
}
```

It creates the dialog window renametargets.

Window has three text edit lines (lineEdit_Target1, lineEdit_Target2,lineEdit_Target3).

When the OK button is pushed I store the text in QString variables.

```
void RenameTargets::on_buttonBox_TargetRename_accepted()
{
    QString Target1NameInput = ui->lineEdit_Target1->text();
    QString Target2NameInput = ui->lineEdit_Target2->text();
    QString Target3NameInput = ui->lineEdit_Target3->text();
}
```

Questions:
(1) How can I set the text of QString Target1NameInput (located on second form: renametargets) to label_Tar1ex (located on main form) as I push the OK button on the dialog.

(2) How can I get to display label_Tar1ex (located on main form) to display on a label in the second form -- called label_CurrentName_Tar1ex.

Basically this is a renaming scheme.....

Comment: after your exec call, check the results of the exec. if it's accepted you can access the object variable in renametargets. Just declare them as variables in the object, not in the method (as you did above).

Comment: Can you post an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is declare `Target1NameInput` and others in your dialog's class instead of your Ok function. That way those variables always "exist" while your dialog exists. If you create them in your Ok function, then they vanish when that function ends, and then you can't get them from your mainWindow anymore.

Move the variable declarations to your dialog's class. (They go in public so other classes can get at em)

```
class RenameTargets : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    QString Target1NameInput; //Side note, variable naming convention says
    QString Target2NameInput; //that variables should start with a lowercase
    QString Target3NameInput; //letter, but totally up to you ;)

    //Your other class stuff goes here
}
```

From that point you can set those variables in your dialog when Ok is pressed.

```
void RenameTargets::on_buttonBox_TargetRename_accepted()
{
    Target1NameInput = ui->lineEdit_Target1->text();
    Target2NameInput = ui->lineEdit_Target2->text();
    Target3NameInput = ui->lineEdit_Target3->text();
}
```

And lastly, access those variables in your mainWindow.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_RenameTargets_clicked()
{
    RenameTargets renametargets;
    renametargets.setModal(true);
    if(renametargets.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) //Check if they clicked Ok
    {
        ui->label_Tar1ex->setText(renametargets.Target1NameInput);
        ui->label_Tar2ex->setText(renametargets.Target2NameInput);
        ui->label_Tar3ex->setText(renametargets.Target3NameInput);
    }

}
```

As for your second question, sending from mainWindow to dialog, you have 2 options as I see it.

1. Set your string variables we created in your dialog class before exec().
2. Pass the text in your dialog constructor.

If option 1, then you simply call `renametargets.Target1NameInput = ui->label_Tar1ex->text();` for each variable before you call `renametargets.exec();` Then in your dialog's ui setup, you set your lineEdits text to those same variables.

Let me know if you want me to explain option 2 for you. ;)

There's also many other options to send variables between classes, this is just 1 of those ways. I believe the conventional thing to do would be to have get and set functions within your dialog class, but for my own personal projects, I find that overkill. Up to you.

Comment: Ya what is option 2? The problem with option 1 is when I create the RenameTargets renametargets; object it automatically initiates, so I can't pass the variables that way. They are empty since I must run RenameTargets renametargets; before renametargets.Target1NameInput = ui->label_Tar1ex->text();

Comment: Look up constructors. Doesn't need an explanation from me I suppose since it's so common. If his is your answer please mark it as such.

Comment: Also, the issue you described is not an issue. Read what I wrote carefully. You create the object, instantiate the variables, then set them in your ui.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (editDocumentDialog->exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
{
    editDocumentDialog->getDataRecord(theDocRecord);
    documents->updateRecord(theDocRecord);
}
```

Comment: (1) mind posting a complete answer? along with the declaration of variables in the object. and (2) what about also passing the variables from the mainwindow to the secondary, So I can display a field "current names"

Answer (score 0):

Why not using signal / slot?

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_RenameTargets_clicked()
{
    RenameTargets renametargets;
    connect(&renametargets, SIGNAL(name_inputted), this, SLOT(update_name_fields);
    ...
}
```

Then emit the signal in on_buttonBox_TargetRename_accepted, and update label_Tar1ex... in slot function. You may want to create RenameTargets in heap so it isn't destroyed immediately after its OK is clicked.